# Cloud got trapped over Ayu Dag mountain in Crimea

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, weather

Personally I was impressed by observing a cloud got trapped over Ayu Dag mountain in Crimea, Russia on 7th April 2021. It is said that it was possible to see the cloud during a few hours, then it disappeared somehow. I guess it's a rare situation and I wonder about the reasons to form a cloud over the summit.
The second photo is on 12 apr.

Any explanation are highly welcomed.
[image: 7 apr]
[image: 12 apr]

Comment: see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenticular_cloud

Comment: An even nicer lenticular cloud over the same mountain: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/373798837791544886/

Comment: Does "trapped" imply that the same droplets of water remain in the cloud for "hours"?

Comment: @DJohnM Yes, but I guess that the water was also  supplied from outside air.